# How to remove the extra rows from a dataframe after doing join operations in Pyspark?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have two dataframe df1 and df2. df1 has around 1 million rows and df2 has around 500k rows. I want to update a column value of df1 by taking matching value and its related column values from df2 and i am using join operations for it?

```
df1 = df1.join(df2, on =[df1.MARKET_SEGMENT == df2.SEGMENT_TYPE, how ='left')
```

after doing the joins i can see that some additional rows are getting added in df1 which i want to remove. there is no primary key column in source file which we can use to drop duplicates records (or additional rows). What can be the other way to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you please share a minimal reproducible example, to allow us to suggest some possible solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

This question can be answered without real data.  However, in the future please supply.

First, joining on a column that is not a primary key will cause issues.  That might not be able to be avoided.

Lets create a sample dataset for marketing.  I am pretending this is the result of the join statement above.

```
#
# 1 - Create sample employee data
#


# array of tuples - data
dat1 = [
    (1,"Smith", "Jane", "2018", "North"),
    (2,"Smith", "John", "2017", "South"),
    (3,"Williams", "Sally", "2016", "East"),
    (4,"Brown", "Sally", "2015", "West"),
    (4,"Brown", "Sally", "2015", "West")
]

# array of names - columns
col1 = ["id", "last_name", "first_name", "year", "segment"]

# make data frame
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=dat1, schema=col1)

# create table
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("marketing")
```

The above code creates both a data frame and temporary view.  I like working in Spark SQL but I will show the the dataframe methods to solve your problem.  The image below shows a display of our data.

[image]

The **distinct()** method looks at every row and drops any duplicates.  There are times that we only want to look at certain columns for row uniqueness.  How do we drop rows then?

[image]

We can see that only one row is a complete

The **dropDuplicates()** method looks at certain columns.  Lets look for unique last names.  See output below.

[image]

Better yet, lets look for unique last and first names.

[image]

Last, we can look at unique first names.

[image]

I am enclosing links to the apache docs on these methods.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropDuplicates.html

https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.distinct.html?highlight=distinct#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.distinct

The pandas library has some more interesting parameters such as first, last, and false.  The first two tell the code which row to keep.  The false parameter tells the code to drop all duplicate rows.

Spark does not support this parameter, however, a row_number() function over a good date can be used the duplicate the logic.

In short, I would try to get a primary key for the row.  Sometimes, people create a hash key from a set of composite columns.  The next step is to determine which method works for your situation.

Comment: what if dates are also getting duplicated many times

Comment: The dropDuplicate() command takes a list of columns to determine uniqueness and drops duplicates.  It all depends on your data.  Since I do not have that, you need to look at the pattern and figure out what makes sense.